# See miniprofiler results from included DLL

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, miniprofiler

I have a Visual studio solution with 3 projects (umbraco cloud site). One of the projects is a website that runs on a webserver (web), it references another project which contains the business logic (core).

Id like to use miniprofiler to profile the referenced DLL when im running the site but i dont seem to be able to see the results on the front end of the site. I can see steps that ive added in the web project however.

Is it possible to do this? Thanks, Jonny

Comment: Can you see mini profiler info for the rest of the site, and just not the referenced DLL?

Comment: @Tim I can yes, if i add it to the views or some code files in the web project, the one thats running the site, i can see them.